# Add ";" after each loop in JSON object

Tags: python, json

I am trying to work out with json to add a ; after each loop of json object. Basically I have a list that I loop and then I add it as a "convert" it to a json:

```
i = 1
for _ in range(3):

    data = {}

    data['country'] = 'SE'
    data['profileNickname'] = 'TEST {}'.format(i)
    i += 1

with open("random.json", "w") as writeJSON:
    writeJSON.write(json.dumps(data, indent=2))
```

however the outprint would just turn out to be a normal json:

```
{
  "country": "SE",
  "profileNickname": "TEST 1",
},
{
  "country": "SE",
  "profileNickname": "TEST 2",
}
```

And my question and what I want to do is that I would like to add `;` after each loop so an outprint would look like:

```
{
  "country": "SE",
  "profileNickname": "TEST 1",
};{
  "country": "SE",
  "profileNickname": "TEST 2",
}
```

I know that would mark it as invalid json but that is my goal and my goal is to be able to add ; after each loop except the last loop of course.

Comment: The shown code would only result in one object in the file, not two

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why do you want to do that?

Comment: found this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924902/parse-non-standard-semicolon-separated-json

Comment: @cricket_007 Oh lord.. That is not what it is supposed to do. I must have been doing something wrong in the code. I will try fix that asap!

Comment: @dddJewelsbbb This is a task I got from a friend that needs it for some application I am not sure so I took it as a challange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why you need it, but that's not a problem :)

```
import json

items = []
for i in range(1, 4):
    items.append({
        'country': 'SE',
        'profileNickname': 'TEST {}'.format(i)
    })

with open("random.json", "w") as writeJSON:
    buffer = ""
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        buffer += json.dumps(item, indent=2)

        if i != len(items) - 1:
            buffer += ';'

    writeJSON.write(buffer)
```

Writes to the file

```
{
  "country": "SE",
  "profileNickname": "TEST 1"
};{
  "country": "SE",
  "profileNickname": "TEST 2"
};{
  "country": "SE",
  "profileNickname": "TEST 3"
}
```

### One more example without using buffer string

```
import json

items = []
for i in range(1, 4):
    items.append({
        'country': 'SE',
        'profileNickname': 'TEST {}'.format(i)
    })

with open("random.json", "w") as writeJSON:
    for i, item in enumerate(items):
        writeJSON.write(json.dumps(item, indent=2))

        if i != len(items) - 1:
            writeJSON.write(';')
```

Comment: Oh hi there! Thank you alot!

It seems to kinda work for me except that it seems to add a ; at the end for me. I am not sure if I did soemthing wrong

Comment: now it doesn't add `;` after the end element as requested in the question example. Should be `;` after EVERY element?

Comment: Oh I think so, Basically ur example that writes shows correctly. as you can see there is no ; at the end of the line. However it seems to add for me but you might be right about every element :)

Comment: That is strange if it doesn't work for you but works for me :D Looks like a copy-paste trouble or etc. Check the files contents copied from my source code and the one you are running

Comment: I just saw, I think it is maybe because I have more elments? It seems like the len(item) for me is 16. Yeah, thats because I have 16 elements for each json object (Not sure if I wrote it right) but what I mean tis the part u have country, profileNickname. I do have some more stuff init = 16 total.

Comment: @Thrillofit86 check it now, I've entered `item` instead of `items`. Just a misspelling :)

Comment: Oh there we go! Yes! Now it works as it supposed to! :)

Comment: Yayyy, Thank you for helping me out! Thought it would be alot harder actually