# Parse Json column (semicolon) in csv using json.loads (python)

Tags: python, json, pandas, parsing

How can I parse Json column in csv file using Python.
Desired output will be values separated by new columns.
Semicolon is used in Json column.
I tried this but it wont work:

```
df["time"] = df['time'].apply(json.loads)
```

CSV columns:

```
 id | day| jsoncol
101| mon | [{"start":645;"end":647;"total":2};{"start":711;"end":750;"total":39};{"start":510;"end":525;"total":15}]
102| tue | [{"start":600;"end":610;"total":10}]
```

Comment: What is the end result you want to see?

Comment: maybe have a look at [how to parse non-standard json](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38924902/parse-non-standard-semicolon-separated-json) ?

Comment: This works after replacing semicolon with colon: `parsed_df = pd.concat([json_normalize(json.loads(js)) for js in df['jsoncol']], keys=df['id'])`. May i check how to also add df['day'] as key? @JörnHees

Comment: The problem, of course, is that's not JSON.  If you received that from a service that advertised it as JSON, then that service has a bug.  If you convert it to JSON, as @soulynn suggested, then you can import it.